# How to see the customer tables in database in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

How to see the customer tables in magento1

Answer (score 4):

Customer tables in magento below are the table used to store customer table .

**customer_entity** : This is the main entity table, where customer information is stored

**customer_entity_datetime**, **customer_entity_decimal**, **customer_entity_int**, **customer_entity_text**, **customer_entity_varchart**: these are the customer entity attribute tables

**customer_form_attribute** : This table is used by magento to define in which form which customer attributes are required. e.g which fields to validate in checkout shipping method form, admin customer forms, etc

Answer (score 3):

Use command below command:

> mysql> use database_name;

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

> mysql> show tables like '%customer_entity%';

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_database_name (%customer_entity%) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| customer_entity                                 |
| customer_entity_datetime                        |
| customer_entity_decimal                         |
| customer_entity_int                             |
| customer_entity_text                            |
| customer_entity_varchar                         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```